# Does [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] retain the UIImage?

Tags: ios, uikit, quartz-2d

I am using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` and was expecting it to retain the image passed in. When I nil the image that is passed in, it is deallocated and any attempt to draw with the color results in a crash. Is this expected behavior or a bug?

```
// MyCustomUIImage is a sub-class with it's own custom data provider
UIImage* encodedImage = [[MyCustomUIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:encodedImage];

// color is then assigned to a singleton so it is never deallocated
// ... later ...

CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineJoin(ctx, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationNone);
CGContextSetMiterLimit(ctx, 0.1f);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, YES);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, YES);
CGContextAddPath(ctx, self.path);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, width);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, NULL);
if (self.glowAmount > 0.0f && self.glowColor.alpha > 0.0f)
{
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ctx, CGSizeZero, self.glowAmount, self.glowColor.CGColor);
}
CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, blendMode);

// *** CRASHES HERE ***
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about whether the image is retained as long the UIColor instance is properly managed and you aren't trying to modify the image yourself after you lose ownership. Chances are it is a bug in your code.

Comment: Perhaps showing some code might help.

Comment: I think I had a similiar problem, I had to make sure that the image was really displayed first, before I was able to set it to nil. Therefore you have to wait one cycle of your main thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIColor does retain the UIImage, but it will not retain the data provider. I was releasing the data provider and that was causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ARC, ARC may think your "color" is never used again , so it will destroy it automatically. It will not appear everytime. It will maybe appear when low memory.

you can fix it like this:

```
UIColor* __autoreleasing color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:encodedImage];
```

Comment: I can't see how `__autoreleasing` will solve this problem. also OP said "// color is then assigned to a singleton so it is never deallocated"

Comment: How does autoreleasing help here? The variable is never freed or nil'd.

Comment: @PsychoDad show you a famous unexpectedly destroy case of UIColor. http://blog.bignerdranch.com/296-arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/ . Because of your code is not enough , I think your `color` is destroy because of ARC. Congratulation to you find the real bug.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the valuable link :)

Answer (score 0):

`UIColor`'s methods `colorWithPatternImage` and `initWithPatternImage.` It turns out these two methods use a lot of memory, way more than any one would expect.

instead of that use `[UIColor initWithRed:0.25 green:0.25 blue:0.25 alpha:1];` or some how use UIImageView behind your current layer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do this as the user is the one drawing the path.